# shell script with tail/grep not working when run via cron - Mint 18.1

Tags: shell, grep, cron, tail, linux-mint

Running my script in a terminal works fine. It also works fine in Mint 18.2 when run at boot via `/etc/rc.local`, but on Mint 18.1 it doesn't work. Also on 18.1 it won't run via `sudo crontab -e`. I'm assuming it's got something to do with the tail/grep part.

Here is the relevant part of my script - up to this point the script works;

```
# Takes a screen capture every time I type a string that matches one from a list
sudo -i tail -fn0 "$path"k.log | \
while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | egrep --line-buffered -i -e "$pattern"
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        matches=$(echo "$line" | egrep --line-buffered -i -o "$pattern")
        cap_split=$(echo "$matches" | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g')
        cap_string=$(echo "$cap_split" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9\\n._-]/_/g')
        sleep 1
        DISPLAY=:0.0 scrot "$path"cap/"$stamp"_"$cap_string".png
        echo -e "### Match found \"$cap_split\" and cap created ###"
    fi
done
```

Why will it only work in the terminal on Mint 8.1 and not from `rc.local` or cron?

Comment: The normal reason is that you call something that is not on your PATH because that is not set the same in `cron`. Another reason may be that it can't access your X11 display.

Comment: Does your script run under `env -i HOME=$HOME /path/to/yourscript`?

Comment: The script runs - just not the part shown above which only works when run from the terminal.